# What is a way to solve this with loops in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, math

I've been coding all night so my head is in a state of shock. I'm trying to do the following, but I just don't get what our professor wants us to do. "Input an unsigned and call it number.. Then input number double values, then output the sum and product of the numbers. (If number is zero, then 0 doubles will be input; the sum of 0 numbers is 0, and the product of 0 numbers is 1)"

I could really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

Edit:

This is what i have so far, The thing I'm currently confused with is on how to make the unsigned variable be the number of double inputs inside of the loop.

```
unsigned number, x;
double double_num, sum;
cout << "Input the number of value: \n";
cin >> number;
for (x = 0; x > number; x++) {
    cin >> double_num;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far.  See also [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `Input an unsigned and call it g` What is the code you have so far for that step?

Comment: So basically, you want us to interpret the instructions for you? Or finish your assignment for you? Neither are really on topic for SO ...

Comment: Seems easy to me. Read one unsigned int input. Call it g. Loop from 0 to g reading a double every iteration. Have two additional variables: one that stores the continuous sum and one that stores the continuous product. Output these variables when you're done looping.

Comment: You appear to have failed to "call it g", and why are you reading the unsigned number multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

What're you having difficulty with?

Here's a start:

```
// Input an unsigned and 
unsigned int g;
cout << "Please Enter an unsigned int value, g" << endl;
cin >> g;
```

---

In your loop, you have:

```
for (x = 0; x > number; x++) {
```

Which means:

> x is set to Zero.
>   While x is *bigger* than some-number, keep going...

When do you think zero is bigger than a number such as 5??
How many times do you think that loop will run??

---

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned g;
    double product(1);
    double sum(0);

    cout << "Input the number of value: \n";
    cin >> g;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < g; x++) {
        double n;
        cout << "Input a number: " <<endl;
        cin >> num;
        product *= num;
        sum += num;
    }

    cout << "The product is" << product << "\n";
    cout << "The sum is" << sum << "\n" << endl;;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what i have so far, The thing I'm currently confused with is on how to make the unsigned variable be the number of double inputs inside of the loop.

"unsigned number;
 int x,sum;
 for (x = 0; x > number; x++) {
  cin >> number;

 }"

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    double g, p=1, s=0;
    while (n-->0 && std::cin >> g) p*=g,s+=g;
    return std::cin
        ? std::cout << s << std::endl << p << std::endl, EXIT_SUCCESS
        : (std::cerr << "Failed to read all inputs" << std::endl, EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You should be sure that you understand each statement and be prepared to justify your choices; if not, you probably haven't learnt anything and will be unlikely to pass your course.